# Android app is not visible in google playstore

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-development

I've successfully published my app in the play console. But if searching for it as user via topic or name is not possible. It is only visible in the Playstore if directly accessing the link (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mastersmate.saily) I'm aware that I have to wait a couple of hours before it is available, but I've published it 4 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can take a few days for the newest apps to appear in the search results. If you've just developed an app and uploaded it to the store, it might take some time for it to become discoverable in search results.

After you've entered your search query, you might find filters or sorting options. Look for a filter that allows you to sort apps by "Newest" or "New" to see the most recent additions to the store.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a rooted device ?? or try to update and upgrade your phone firmware.

Answer (score -1):

The below code will help you to find app in playstore

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // this is your playstore url id parameter
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
```